# How to add a Countup timer on Android?

Tags: android

I'm currently doing my project and would like to add a timer for my android Sudoku game. I need to  know the source code and how to put the source code into my Sudoku game. Please help i need it urgently :(

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Note that this is not "Write my code for me" site. If you have a specific problem please let us know what it is, and what did you do - trying to solve it. Also, if it is your homework - please tag the question as such.

Answer (score 21):

Layout XML:

```
<Chronometer
android:id="@+id/simpleChronometer"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Code:

```
Chronometer simpleChronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.simpleChronometer); // initiate a chronometer

simpleChronometer.start(); // start a chronometer
```

[image]

Answer (score 15):

If you're on android and need a timer which ticks each second you can create the following subclass of `CountDownTimer`. It can easily be modified to tick at whatever interval you want.

```
import android.os.CountDownTimer;

public abstract class CountUpTimer extends CountDownTimer {
        private static final long INTERVAL_MS = 1000;
        private final long duration;

    protected CountUpTimer(long durationMs) {
        super(durationMs, INTERVAL_MS);
        this.duration = durationMs;
    }

    public abstract void onTick(int second);

    @Override
    public void onTick(long msUntilFinished) {
        int second = (int) ((duration - msUntilFinished) / 1000);
        onTick(second);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        onTick(duration / 1000);
    }
}
```

And then use it like

```
CountUpTimer timer = new CountUpTimer(30000) {
    public void onTick(int second) {
        timerView.setText(String.valueOf(second));
    }
};

timer.start();
```

Comment: How do you stop the timer?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html#cancel()

`timer.cancel()`

Answer (score 12):

I might be too late but what the hell.  Here's a small example of how you could create a `CountUpTimer`.  This code was inspired by [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html).

https://gist.github.com/MiguelLavigne/8809180c5b8fe2fc7403

Answer (score 5):

Android's [`CountDownTimer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) should fit your needs. The documentation also provides a small example which will help you.

**EDIT :**  for counting up I think Android's [`Chronometer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html) will be the easiest choice.

**EDIT2:**  I think you should start [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html).

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply Ovidiu Latcu but i'm looking for CountUpTimer :(

Comment: After reading the Chronometer, I'm still confuse on how to start with the code

Comment: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ChronometerDemo.html

Comment: Is is possible to start the time without button because i'm creating a Sudoku game. If the user click "new game" and it bring to the sudoku puzzle that is when the time start

Comment: of course. you need to follow the api more carefully. the `Chronometer` has a `start()` method that can be invoked for example in `onCreate()` of your `Activity`.

Comment: I try to implement the chronometerdemo into my sudoku but when i run, the whole sudoku game override into chronometerdemo

Comment: ok i think i did a copy and paste of the code in http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ChronometerDemo.html and put in into my sudoku game under the onCreate()

Comment: you "think"? you don't just copy/paste code all the time... you code it yourself. do you have any experience developing Android so far?

Comment: Yep i did install the sdk. Now my sudoku is working but i followed the Hello, Android book cause i do not have any background on android and now would like to improve on it by adding a count up timer to it

Answer (score 2):

```
_countTimer = new CountDownTimer(40000, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                String _millis=String.valueOf(40-(millisUntilFinished/1000));
                CameraScreen._timerTxt.setText("0."+_millis);
            }
 _countTimer.start();
```

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completion and because I had to do it. Here's a Kotlin version:

```
import android.os.CountDownTimer

abstract class CountUpTimer(private val secondsInFuture: Int, countUpIntervalSeconds: Int) : CountDownTimer(secondsInFuture.toLong() * 1000, countUpIntervalSeconds.toLong() * 1000) {

    abstract fun onCount(count: Int)

    override fun onTick(msUntilFinished: Long) {
        onCount(((secondsInFuture.toLong() * 1000 - msUntilFinished) / 1000).toInt())
    }
}
```

And here's how to use it

```
val counter = object: CountUpTimer(30, 1){
      
      override fun onCount(count: Int) {
          Log.i("Counter", "Counting: $count")
      }
                
      override fun onFinish() {
          Log.i("Counter", "Counting done")
      }
}
counter.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that chronometer uses something called  system.elapsedRealTime internally which is the time from when the phone first booted.

In a practical situation on power down chonometers readings go wrong even if the trime is saved previously.

Answer (score 1):

I spent few hours to find KISS solution for the Count Up Timer.
If we use View Class to display the time definitely the easiest solution is to use
Chronometer class.

Unfortunately, it does not work without the View.
I wish to show the time in Action Bar that is why I needed the String with the time without the view.
Here is my idea:

I am using java.util.Timer and  java.util.TimerTask and Kotlin in Android Studio.

```
  private fun stopwatch() {
    var num : Long = 0L
    val timer : Timer = Timer()
    val tt : TimerTask = object : TimerTask(){
        override fun run() {
            num+=1000L
            println(TimerUtil.timerDisplay(num))
        }
    }
    timer.schedule(tt, 0L, 1000L)
}
```

The helper function to format the String to MM:SS format:

```
class TimerUtil {
companion object {
    fun timerDisplay(time: Long): String {
        val minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(time)
        val seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(time) - TimeUnit
            .MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(time))

        return " %02d:%02d".format(minutes, seconds)
    }
}
```

}